# Unable to create a constant value in LINQ to EF query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to retrieve data from a user class `webpages_membership` for verifying a token password change.

Wehn I try to run this query to get the necessary information from the database:

```
bool any = ttf.webpages_Membership
    .Any(x => x.UserId.Equals(userid)
         && x.PasswordVerificationToken == rt
         && x.PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate < DateTime.Now);

if (any == true) {

}
```

I get this exception

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'DBContext.Models.Customers'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

How can I avoid that exception?

Comment: What type is `UserId` and  `PasswordVerificationToken`?

Comment: UserId is an Int and PasswordVerificationToken a string

Comment: Doesn't look like it has anything to do with the code you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, to ensure that the LINQ expression only have constant values. Do also use `==` instead of `.Equals` (I'm not sure if `.Equals` can be correctly processed by LINQ. Perhaps it's possible, but I'm sure that `==` works fine).

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

ttf.webpages_Membership
    .Any(x => x.UserId == userid && 
         x.PasswordVerificationToken == rt &&
         x.PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate < now);
```

LINQ examines the expression tree of the lambda predicate, and can transfer constant values to the server. I think it doesn't treat `DateTime.Now` as a constant, unless you capture it in a variable as shown.